# Writing return values from class objects to csv-file

Tags: python, csv, class, object

Im converting some json data to csv data and using class objects to structure the data.

The issue that I am experiencing is writing the object returns with writerow. If my class objects return more than one value it writes just fine, but if i combine that object with a object that only returns one value I get an error. "Error: need to escape, but no escapechar set".
As long as I dont combine the two variants of object returns It writes just fine, but combining the two will produce the error above.

I have tried other ways, and know that I can get the result I am after by writing on return at a time like this: class().object()[i], but there must be a more elegant way of doing it.
When just writing the object that returns multiple values it does what I want it to do, but as long as I try to combine it with a object that only return one value the error occurs.
I have also tried combining the result of both objects in a list, but that leaves me with another issue, Parentheses around each object return will be written to the file.
Tried finding a way to write to the same line of the CSV-file in two steps, but have not been able to.

```py
class myClass():

    def __init__(self):
        
        pass
        
      
    def name(self,index):
        
        name=(nl_obj['employes'][index]['name'])
        self.fullname=name
        name=name.split( )
        self.firstname=name[0]
        self.lastname=name[-1]
        return (self.firstname,self.lastname)

    
    def department(self,index):
        self.team=nl_obj['employes'][index]['department']
        return(self.department)
    
nlLifter().department(0)

with open(filepath+'csvFileName'+str(0)+'.csv','w',newline='') as csvfile:
    csvwriter=csv.writer(csvfile,delimiter=',',
                         quotechar='', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
    csvwriter.writerow(['Heading1','Heading2'])
    csvwriter.writerow([
        [myClass().team(0)],
        [myClass().name(0)]
    ])
```

The result I am trying to produce is to combine the two objects name and team to be written on the same row in the csv file. I is crucial that the CSV-file only have 2 rows of data.

Comment: Can you [edit] the question to give an example for what `nl_obj` contains?  This is needed to be able to test your script.

Comment: nl_obj is the imported json file. It contains strings of text and numbers. That part is working like it should aswell as the parsing part. Team returns a single string, name returns a tuplet : ('Firstname' , 'Lastname')

Comment: The reason for the error message is that somewhere in your data there is a comma. When this happens the CSV library needs to add an escape character. Normally the entry has quotes added to it, but you have disabled that. (why?) A package like Excel (or Pandas) would correctly parse any quoting that is added so I would advise you don't disable that feature. You could add an `escapechar='\'` parameter.